# react-admin authentication flow not working

Tags: jwt, react-admin

Working on [authentication react-admin using JWT](https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/07/02/manage-your-jwt-react-admin-authentication-in-memory.html) token and storing in memory as closure variable.

**Creating AuthToken from Django works fine, it's emitting the Token with user info as JSON.**

Here is [inMemoryJWT Manager](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-in-memory-jwt)

#### File: inMemoryJwt.js

```
// https://github.com/marmelab/ra-in-memory-jwt
const inMemoryJWTManager = () => {
    let inMemoryJWT = null;
    let isRefreshing = null;

    // Token code goes here
    const getToken = () => inMemoryJWT;

    const setToken = (token) => {
        inMemoryJWT = token;
        return true;
    };

    const ereaseToken = () => {
        inMemoryJWT = null;
        return true;
    }

    return {
        ereaseToken,
        getToken,
        setToken,
    }
};

export default inMemoryJWTManager();
```

#### File: AuthProvider.js

```
oryJWTManager';

const authProvider = {
    login: ({ username, password }) => {
        const request = new Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token-auth/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });

        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Response status ' + response.status )
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                console.log('response.json is ');
                console.log(response.json());
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {

                console.log(' about to set token in storage .......... ');
                JwtManager.setToken(token);
                const decodedToken = decodeJwt(token);

                # Its not setting in localstorage 
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                console.log('Token from lS : -------------',localStorage.getIdentity('token'));
                localStorage.setItem('permissions', decodedToken.permissions);
            })
            .then(auth => {
                localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(auth));
            })
            .catch(response  => {
                console.log('Catch : ' );
                console.log(response.json());
                throw new Error('Network errorkkkkkkkkkkkkk')
            });
    },

    logout: () => {
        localStorage.setItem('not_authenticated', true);
        localStorage.removeItem('auth');
        localStorage.removeItem('role');
        localStorage.removeItem('login');
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        localStorage.removeItem('avatar');

        inMemoryJWT.ereaseToken();
        return Promise.resolve();
    },

    checkError: ({ status }) => {
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            inMemoryJWT.ereaseToken();
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();

        //         return status === 401 || status === 403
        //             ? Promise.reject( { redirectTo: '/login' , logoutUser: false} )
        //             : Promise.resolve();
    },

    checkAuth: () => {

        return inMemoryJWT.getToken() ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access',  message: 'login.required'  });

        //         localStorage.getItem('auth')
        //         ? Promise.resolve()
        //         : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access',  message: 'login.required'  }),
    },
    getPermissions: () => {
        return inMemoryJWT.getToken() ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();

        //         const role = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
        //         return role ? Promise.resolve(role) : Promise.reject();
    },

    getIdentity: () => {
        try {
            const { id, fullName, avatar } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
            return Promise.resolve({ id, fullName, avatar });
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        // return {
        //     id: localStorage.getItem('login'),
        //     fullName: localStorage.getItem('user'),
        //     avatar: localStorage.getItem('avatar'),
        // };
    },


}


export default authProvider;
```

#### App.js

```
 const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
     if (!options.headers) {
         options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
     }
     const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
     options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
     return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
 };


const dataProvider = drfProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token-auth/', httpClient);

const App = () => (  

    <Admin  title=""
            loginPage={Login}
            catchAll={NotFound}
            logoutButton={PfsLogoutButton}
            authProvider={authProvider}
            dataProvider={dataProvider} 
            catchAll={NotFound} 
            dashboard={Dashboard} disableTelemetry>
```

#### The problem

The problem I am facing is to, It's not setting in-memory or local storage, also I get the message in the footer on the login button clicked. I am breaking my head with it for quite some time. Let me know if you need any other info.
[image: response.json is not a function]

#### Login required error for every page

[image]

#### HTTP Response goes here

[image]

Comment: what do you get when logging the response from the login fetch
console.log('response.json is ');
console.log(response.json());

Comment: I get what I am expecting, the token with user info, added image in question.

Comment: Okay, in the next "then" block, you have: localStorage.getIdentity('token')). I'm not aware of any getIdentity method with localStorage. are you trying to getItem or use the getIdentity method from the JWT object? I also notice that you are not returning anything from this "then" block, but there is another after it: then(auth => ...)

Comment: response.json() is not a function.... why am i getting this ? whats wrong in that.. I guess ? finding an answer will solve my problem. I guess strongly...